# question on wrap column with SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

I had problem when keyboards up, The error occured "bottom overflowed by xx pixels".
So I resolved the problem by Wrapping column with SingleChildScrollView, and I wonder how It can happen? I s there special trick with SingleChildScrollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the keyboard takes up padding space from screen estate. So wrapping the column with SingleChildScrollView() essentially handles that by making your screen scrollable.

Hope this helps✌

Edit:
Also the second solution given by @EdwynZN is perfectly  alright.
It just has one issue, if you have textfields that are in the region where the keyboard lies, the user won't be able to see them until they lower their keyboard. And that isn't considered a good UX practice.

So using SingleChildScrollView() is the best way to go, in regards to UI/UX.

Answer (score 0):

SingleChildScrollView allows to scroll an area of the space if there is not enough to show the widget (in this case the column). When the keyboard appears the amount of space of the screen is reduced and it shows the overflow because the column cannot show the whole list of children, that's why you would need a scroll area. Another solution if you don't need to scroll is to change the parameter `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in the scaffold